# Can you reset the DI container in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

We have several websites running on the same ASP.NET Core codebase.  There's a SiteId in the appsettings.json that defines which website should be loaded from the database.  We then have a Singleton set up:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<Site>(provider =>
{
    short siteId = configuration.GetValue<short>("CoreSettings:SiteID");
    var db = provider.GetRequiredService<SomeDatabaseService>();
    return db.GetSite(siteId);
}
```

The Site object is very static.  It has basic data like CompanyName and Phone that rarely changes.  However, this data can occasionally change and we'd like the Site singleton to get updated.

I know that we could change the Site to scoped, but this seems like a lot of DI overhead when the Site can go months without changing.  Plus we'd have to change a lot of other services that are obviously singletons to scoped, because they depend on the Site.

Is there a way to tell the DI container to reset?  I basically want to say "Hey DI, throw everything away and rebuild".

Right now, we're having to reset the application pool in IIS to see any changes to the Site.

Comment: Yes, the trick is to restart the web application.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to tell the DI container to reset? I basically want to say "Hey DI, throw everything away and rebuild".

No. At least not in the default DI container.

TBH sounds much more like caching problem then DI one. I would consider reworking approach for getting the `Site` by introducing in-memory cache with some expirations set up and/or management endpoint to fetch new values.

> but this seems like a lot of DI overhead

I would say that switching to `Scoped` and corresponding DI overhead itself is very minimal, the only overhead worth considering is the unnecessary querying the database - but this should be mitigated via cache.

P.S.

If `Site` was not stored in the database but in configuration file another notable approach would be using `Options` pattern with [`IOptionsMonitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-7.0#ioptionsmonitor).

Comment: I do actually have the Site object in an in memory cache.  I was trying to simplify the question by stripping that piece out.  I agree that I can easily switch to scoped and I'm sure I won't really notice a performance hit.  It just seems strange to me that I have to make something scoped that is a singleton 99.9% of the time.  Even worse, I have to convert a lot of other clearly singleton classes to scoped (because they depend on Site).  A DI reset sure would be useful for this use case.

Comment: @BenMills _"that is a singleton 99.9% of the time"_ - that means that this is not a singleton. _"I have to convert a lot of other clearly singleton classes to scoped"_ - make `Site` transient, if scope is needed to refresh it - you always create one.

Comment: Converting site into Transient is not the solution, because -with MS.DI- Singletons can depend on Transient services, but once a transient changes, the singletons will keep referring to the old transient instance. In that case the service becomes [Captive](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/).

Comment: @Steven yes, thank you for correction. Then transient/singleton factory or just updatable singleton wrapper can be the solution.